# Cypher - atomic insert if node is absent

Tags: neo4j, match, case, cypher

I would like to write a single Cypher statement that tests for the existence of a path, adding it if the part is not present.

Consider path `(:A)-[:REL]->(:B{id:123})`, then the existence of the path can be tested by

`OPTIONAL MATCH p = (:A)-[:REL]->(:B{id:123}) RETURN CASE COUNT(p) WHEN 0 THEN false ELSE true END`

Which returns false if the path doesn't exist, or true if it does.

The path can be created by

`CREATE (b:B{id:123}), (b)<-[:REL]-(:A)`

However, if these statements are combined, so that if the path is missing then it is created, Cypher generates a syntax error

`OPTIONAL MATCH p = (:A)-[:REL]->(:B{id:123}) RETURN CASE COUNT(p) WHEN 0 THEN CREATE (b:B{id:123}), (b)<-[:REL]-(:A) END`

Is there a correct way to perform this atomic creation of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the `MERGE` statement instead of trying to interrogate whether the node is there first.

This statement will create the nodes and relationships if it does not already exist and won't create it if it is already there.

```
MERGE (b:B {id:123} )<-[:REL]-(:A)
return *
```

Comment: Thanks - a case of read the manual! [merge](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html)